# LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING unavailable for proximity alerts?

Tags: android, android-emulator

After registering for a proximity alert for a given set of coordinates via

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LOCATION, location); // custom payload
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

locationManager.addProximityAlert(location.getLatitude(),
    location.getLongitude(), location.getRadius(), -1, pendingIntent);
```

I am getting intents delivered to my service when entering or leaving a configured location. So far, so good.

Unfortunately, none of these delivered intents carries the boolean extra `LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING` that identifies the type of location change (enter or exit), which can be retrieved via `Intent.getBooleanExtra`. My observation is based on AOSP 2.1 and AOSP 2.2. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), this extra should always be present.

Is there anything that I have missed? Is there a limitation with regards to this extra when running using mock locations on the emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turned out, this seems to be caused by putting in an additional serializable extra into the PendingIntent. As a workaround, perform the serialization on your own or just store primitive types or Strings if an extra payload is required.

Comment: Problem still seems to be there as of 4.1.2 ... (facepalm) Just wonder, is anybody going to fix this?

Comment: @deville You should raise a bug issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list if you want to see this fixed.